# MySQL queries optimization

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

So I've been working on an IRC game for one year now, written in PHP and using a PHP to IRC framework.

Recently, I've added the ability to archive scores (they're being reseted every couple hundreds of games) which forced me to update various admin functions.
I've just updated a function that allows me to merge two players (some users don't bother looking for their old password etc...) in order to merge archived scores too (in case a reset has occurred before I find the duplicated accounts).

The score-merging part (below) works has intended, but I'm wondering if I can optimize the process because I find it rather heavy (but can't think of something better) :

```
$from_stats = $this->db->query("SELECT `games`, `wins`, `points`, `date_archive` FROM ".$this->dbprefix."score WHERE `id`=".$id1." AND `channel`='".$gamechan."' GROUP BY `date_archive`"); // get scores for the original account
$to_stats = $this->db->query("SELECT `games`, `wins`, `points`, `date_archive` FROM ".$this->dbprefix."score WHERE `id`=".$id2." AND `channel`='".$gamechan."' GROUP BY `date_archive`"); // get scores for the duplicated account
$from_games = array();
$from_wins = array();
$from_points = array();
$from_date = array();
while (list($fromstats_games,$fromstats_wins,$fromstats_points,$fromstats_date) = $this->db->fetchRow($from_stats)) { // build score arrays for the original account
    $from_games[count($from_games)] = $fromstats_games;
    $from_wins[count($from_wins)] = $fromstats_wins;
    $from_points[count($from_points)] = $fromstats_points;
    $from_date[count($from_date)] = $fromstats_date;
}
$to_games = array();
$to_wins = array();
$to_points = array();
$to_date = array();
while (list($tostats_games,$tostats_wins,$tostats_points,$tostats_date) = $this->db->fetchRow($to_stats)) { // build score arrays for the duplicated account
    $to_games[count($to_games)] = $tostats_games;
    $to_wins[count($to_wins)] = $tostats_wins;
    $to_points[count($to_points)] = $tostats_points;
    $to_date[count($to_date)] = $tostats_date;
}
foreach ($from_date as $key1 => $id1_date) {
    foreach ($to_date as $key2 => $id2_date) {
        if ($id1_date == $id2_date) { // merge scores if dates match
            $from_games[$key1] += $to_games[$key2];
            $from_wins[$key1] += $to_wins[$key2];
            $from_points[$key1] += $to_points[$key2];
            $this->db->query("UPDATE ".$this->dbprefix."score SET `games`=".$from_games[$key1].", `wins`=".$from_wins[$key1].", `points`=".$from_points[$key1]." WHERE `id`=".$id1." AND `channel`='".$gamechan."' AND `date_archive`='".$id1_date."'");
            break;
        }
    }
}
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM ".$this->dbprefix."score WHERE `id`=".$id2); // delete all entries for the duplicated account
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one tip: after all use this query (if You have appropriate privilages)

```
$this->db->query("OPTIMIZE TABLE ".$this->dbprefix."score");
```

This should cause all indexes in this table to be recalculated. You'll notice the index file size has changed to 1kb (or few bytes)

Comment: one more thing, instead of DELETE FROM consider using TRUNCATE TABLE - if there is no triggers that should be executed, this is a way faster than DELETE

Comment: Yes I'm using it on other cases, but here I needed to delete selected entries.
Thanks for your inputs :)